# comparacion arrays php

Tags: php, array

hola a todos espero que me puedan ayudar tengo el siguiente problema 
tengo 2 arrays y necesito crear un tercer array con el key del array1 y el value del array2 haciendo un match con el value del array1 con el key del array2 y en caso de q no haya match que me muestre el valor del array1

```php
$array1 = ["value1" => "nombre", "value2" => "apellido", "value3" => "email"];
$array2 = ["nombre" => "maria", "apellido" => "perez"];

//ejemplo de lo que deberia retornar el array3
$array3 = ["value1" => "maria", "value2" => "perez", "value3" => "email"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías lograr lo que quieres con un `foreach`  que leería `$array1` y dentro del bucle un ternario que evalúe si `$array2` tiene una llave con el valor actual de `$array`. Si la tuviere pondrías en `$newArray` el dato de `$array2` cuyo clave sea el valor actual de `$array1`. En caso contrario, pondrías la clave de `$array1`.

Parece un trabalengua :), pero es muy simple.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
$array1 = ["value1" => "nombre", "value2" => "apellido", "value3" => "email"];
$array2 = ["nombre" => "maria", "apellido" => "perez"];

#Nuevo array
$newArray=array();

foreach ($array1 as $k=>$v) {
    $newArray[$k]=isset($array2[$v]) ? $array2[$v] : $array1[$k];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

**Salida:**

Justo lo que dijiste que querías:

```
Array
(
    [value1] => maria
    [value2] => perez
    [value3] => email
)
```

Comment: gracias lo había logrado pero usando muchas lineas de código en tu solución lo haces super sencillo

Answer (score 3):

```html
$array1 = ["value1" => "nombre", "value2" => "apellido", "value3" => "email"];
$array2 = ["nombre" => "maria", "apellido" => "perez"];

$array3 = [];
$array2 = array_values($array2);
$i = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v){
    if (isset($array2[$i])){
        $array3[$k] = $array2[$i];
    }
    else{
        $array3[$k] = $v;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```